# hard drive lock, impossible to enter bios

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios

This morning I have encountered a really unpleasant surprise. My notebook refused to turn on. I didn't drop it, haven't installed anything new and all of a sudden, throughout the night, it simply stopped working.

I've set a password on the hard drive once so it always greets me with this blue form asking for authorization, but today's was a bit different, because besides the usual name of the drive "Samsung SSD and so on", there was also a disturbing word "Lock". Nevertheless, I entered the password, the screen was black but bright so I kept on waiting and after about 10 minutes the computer became quite hot, a welcome screen appeared and just the moment I felt relieved, the sofb restarted. After that it went on a freaking merry-go-round and kept showing me the POST and manufacturer's logo in turns.

It's not responding to F8 when I try to get it working in the safe mode and it's impossible to enter the BIOS because it asks for a system password which I have never set (it was possible to change BIOS settings earlier without any password).

I've managed to boot it from a DVD but it doesn't see the hard drive. I've tried the "take the battery out-unplug-hold power button for 15 seconds-plug the AC adapter back in" method, but as you can see, here I am, asking for your help. Any physical ingerence is not an option because there's a warranty sticker on one of the screws and I can't get it to the service for at least 5 next days.

My notebook:
Lenovo G510 12GB RAM
Core i7-4700MQ (2.4 GHz)
HD: Samsung SSD 840 Evo 500GB
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Any advices highly appreciated

Comment: Pull the hard drive, can you enter bios now?

Comment: As I've said, the warranty voids if I remove the sticker and I'm not able to get the laptop fixed till next Thursday, and the question is if there is anything I can do to get it working earlier

Comment: Removing/reinstalling the hard drive should not void the warranty, but if you are concerned then wait til Thursday. I don't see any logical step other than removing the hard drive as Moab suggested.

Comment: Many/most laptop manufacturers have a seal/sticker that is used to determine if the body of the laptop has been opened. Evidence of tampering certainly does void the warranty (this may or may not be the case if you have a warranty through the retailer). I'd say check the agreements.

Comment: I have never seen a seal in USA, have bought hundreds of laptops factory direct and retail. First thing I do on a New laptop is remove the drive and make a full disk image of it.